# AngularJS Project Loads wrong HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, eclipse

I am working on a maven project with spring boot and angularjs.
Today I changed some simple html tags and noticed it wont change when testing in localhost.(odd because on Friday it did)

How i route my HTML with angular:

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "./html/homePage.html",
    controller : "some-controller"
})
```

So when changing something in on of my pages it wont change in localhost.(Not hidden or something.Its just my structure from Friday)

I tested and changed homePage.html in homePage**1**.html. Started again and ofc it wont render anything because the file doesnt exists.

When I moved the somePage.html from my HTML folder and started the project again it rendered the page(but again the page from Friday). Again its rendered a File which isn't even in the folder.

When calling the page static via localhost/html/somePage.html it always shows the old page from last week. (with and without the edited file in path)

What I tried:

- Restart Eclipse
- restart whole pc
- cleaned proejct(via eclipse)
- cleaned and reinstalled with maven
- updated project via maven

Does someone have a solution? (before i become insane)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the cache. Free the cache of the browser and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Got it.

The error was a mix of eclipse cache and a Plugin.
Noticed that Egit, which wont worked with Spring Boot Suite, magically fixed itself and activated itself.

After resetting the Head of Git and deleting the cache in eclipse the changes are rendered again.